# Mysql has gone away ao executar 'DELETE' utilizando conexão PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Quando executo a instrução SQL `delete from proposta_envio_fisico WHERE idProposta = 209940`, minha conexão com o MySQL é desabilitada (mysql has gone away) após 40 segundos. 
Ao monitorar a execução deste instrução é obtido o seguinte resultado:

[image: MYSQL - SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST]

A instrução fica executando até realizar o time out. Mas se tentarmos executar a instrução diretamente pelo console do MySQL, a mesma é executada corretamente.

A minha configuração de 'Time Out' do MySQL esta setada em 40 segundos, mas a mesma não pode ser alterada.

A tabela em questão possui apenas 240 registros.

O código que esta sendo executado no PHP é o:

```
mysql_query('delete from proposta_envio_fisico WHERE idProposta =' . $id, $conexao);
```

Mesmo alterando a conexão para PDO, é retornado o mesmo erro (mysql has gone away) na execução da aplicação.

Comment: `idProposta` tem indice? tentou dar um drop ou repair na tabela? parece estranho mesmo.

Comment: Sim, idProposta é index. O estranho é que quando executada no console, a query é realizada instantaneamente. Mas com a conexão PHP ela só fica com o status updating.

Comment: a função [mysql_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) foi depreciada no PHP 5.5 e removida no PHP 7.0 .Use a extensão [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: @AugustoVasques Mesmo trocando a conexão do sistema para PDO, o erro persiste.

Comment: Verifique a conexão para ver se ela está ativa.

Comment: @AugustoVasques A conexão morre, pois excede os 40 segundos de espera do retorno.

Comment: Verifique antes do delete e depois do delete use mysqli_error() para imprimir a mensagem de erro.

Comment: Nos mostre mais do código! :)

Comment: @AugustoVasques Sim, após os 40 segundos a conexão morre. Justamente porque a o 'set time out' do MySQL esta configurado para este tempo. O problema aqui é o porque quando a instrução SLQ é efetuada no console, ela é realizada em milissegundos, entretanto, quando é enviada da aplicação, a instrução SQL atinge o limite de 40 segundos ocasionando o encerramento da conexão. A questão não é porque a conexão morre, mas sim, porque a instrução SQL leva mais de 40 segundos para ser executada quando enviada da aplicação.